# When is a matrix similar to the companion matrix of its characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial, companion-matrices, similar-matrices

Let $A$ be a complex matrix and $A_c$ the companion matrix of its characteristic polynomial. From what I have read, I believe the following two statements to be true:

1. not every $A$ is similar to $A_c$, and
2. $A$ is similar to $A_c$ if $A$ has a simple spectrum.

Is $A$ similar to $A_c$ if and only if the spectrum of $A$ is simple? Or, Are there other conditions under which we can have $A \sim A_c$?

I am particularly interested in complex Hermitian matrices.

Comment: Are you familiar with the theory of Jordan normal form? The problem reduces to computing the Jordan normal form of a companion matrix.

Comment: This explains it clearly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix#Characterization

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Do you mean by "Theory of Jordan normal form" that every complex matrix can be decomposed as $A = PJP^{-1}$ where $J$ is the Jordan canonical form of $A$ and $P$ is nonsigular? I know that. If $A$ and $A_c$ have the same Jordan form, then they must be similar. But, can we say something about $A \sim A_c$ without making reference to the Jordan form of $A_c$? Perhaps the answer is simply "no" but I am not sure at this point.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Ok, I think I get it now. The statements $A \sim A_c$ and "the minimal polynomial of $A$ has degree $n$" are equivalent. If I am not wrong, the second statement implies that the spectrum of $A$ is simple so that "$A \sim A_c$ if and only if $A$ has a simple spectrum."

Comment: @Goku: $A \sim A_c$ _is_ a statement about the Jordan normal form of $A_c$. It is not true that this condition implies that $A$ has simple spectrum; you can find examples with $A$ nilpotent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For sake of having an answer, let's turn the comments to this question into one.)

The minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial of a companion matrix are equal. So, if $A\sim A_c$, the minimal and characteristic polynomials of $A$ are equal, too. In other words, in the Jordan form of $A$, every eigenvalue is associated with only one Jordan block. Alternatively speaking, the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue is equal to $1$.

When $A$ is Hermitian, geometric multiplicities and algebraic multiplicities coincide. Hence the above necessary and sufficient condition reduces to that all eigenvalues of $A$ are simple, i.e. $A$ has distinct eigenvalues.